# How to add tile layer to map using mapboxgl.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Here m adding tile created using tiff

```
mapboxgl.accessToken ='pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2F1cmF2Y2F0c3RlY2giLCJhIjoiY2l1cGo0MTl4MDAxajJ1bng5a2xieTY0diJ9.0fDXNulI91U85ngSc4jGCg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
  zoom: 13,
  center: [-122.447303, 37.753574]
});

map.on('load', function () {
  map.addSource('terrain-data', {
    type: 'raster',
    url:'mapbox://gaurav.2on6cgzq'
  });
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "terrain-data",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "terrain-data",
    "source-layer": "contour",
    "layout": {
      "line-join": "round",
      "line-cap": "round"
    },
    "paint": {
      "line-color": "#ff69b4",
      "line-width": 1
    }
  });
});
```

I am getting :

> Error: Source layer "contour" does not exist on source "terrain-data"
>   as specified by style layer "terrain-data"

Comment: I am curious why your are choosing to use raster instead of vector. Are you going to try to use a custom style or save some memory perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe the `"source-layer": "contour"` is applicable for raster sources whatsoever. See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/ So get rid of that line.Looks like you will need a `"tileSize": 256` option included as well on the source.

Also your layout and paint options are going to be unneeded as well.Those are options for vector or geojson sources. Those types of controls are not available on raster.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to simply edit the tile layer in Mapbox Studio, and then upload it to mapbox.js. This way all you have to do is provide the link to the style as a source (Mapbox has a TON of documentation for this).